# File saved in Excel (Win 10) not found in File Explorer

Tags: excel, windows, csv, text-files

I saved a simple text file as a .csv and .txt from a fresh version of MS Excel (Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2111 Build 16.0.14701.20254) 64-bit).  Excel still sees the file after save, but Word and File Explorer does not.

Since I just installed this version of Excel, I suspect a bug. Should I check anything else before I report to MS?  Where should I report it?

Comment: What about in windows explorer or command prompt / shell?

Comment: Go to the directory you _think_ the file should be, Hold Shift, right click and pick "Open command window here". Then, write `dir` to see all files and directories within that folder. Also, could we know what folder in particular you are trying to save to?

Comment: If your Store it in a OneDrive Folder, you should check If the file is sychronized correctly.